# Extension to class for NSCoding protocol conformance

Tags: ios, swift

I need to extend a class for NSCoding protocol conformance. This is what I tried:

```
extension GTLTasksTask : NSCoding {

    public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    }

    public convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }

}
```

But I get two errors:
1. Initializer requirement 'init(coder:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'GTLTasksTask'
2. Convenience initializer for 'GTLTasksTask' must delegate (with 'self.init')

SomeClass in this example does not have a designated initialiser, though it's super class has an init method. But as per swift documentation convenience initialisers cannot invoke super.init.
I tried making init(coder) a designated initialiser, but that isn't allowed in an extension

Is it not possible to conform this to NSCoding via an extension?

Comment: @dcmaxx seems to have a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631727/adding-nscoding-as-an-extension

Answer (score -4):

Add the `Require` keyword. Tested with xCode 6.0 (tested in playground)

```
extension GLTasksTask : NSCoding {

    public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    }

    public required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work, the error says the required initialiser cannot be declared in the extension. I ran the following code in the playground and the same error: class first : NSObject {
    var name = "string"
}

class second : first {
    var age:Int
    override init() {
        age = 21
    }
}
extension second : NSCoding {   
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    }
    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            self.init()
    }
}